# JS: What's wrong with this? Trying to click a link to bring up a window.prompt

Tags: javascript, clipboard, alert, prompt

I know this is so basic, but for some reason it's just not doing anything at all when I click the link, and maybe I'm too overworked and brainfried to spot the issue right now?, lol.

I declared the external js file like this, in the html page (as usual):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

In the js file I have this code:

```
    function copyToClipboard(text) {
      window.prompt ("Copy to Clipboard: Ctrl+C (Windows) or Cmd+C for Mac | Enter", text);
    }
```

Finally, I'm calling the function in my PHP file exactly like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"  title="Copy ' . $mail . ' to your Clipboard" onClick="copyToClipboard(' . $mail . ');">Copy Address to Clipboard</a>'
```

When viewing the source of the page, the call looks like this (shorthand):

```
copyToClipboard(someaddress@domain.com);
```

When I put an alert call at the very top of the js file, before any functions, it does pop up, so the link to it is fine, but if I put a test alert inside of the actual function, it never pops. My only thought now is, does there need to be a quote visible in the rendered html source on each side of the email address?

Comment: I think you need to add some quotes so that your call looks like this: copyToClipboard('someaddress@domain.com');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript have to be quoted.

```
copyToClipboard("someaddress@domain.com");
```

Comment: I knew it! lol, I was too burnt out last night to fight with the proper way to format quotes. Thanks all.